# Install MS Office (home and student edition) on more than one Mac?

Tags: ms-office, license

If you purchased the home and student edition of Microsoft office, can you legally install the software on more than one computer?

Comment: You had two questions in here. This site works better when there is only one question per question. That way, it's easier for other people to find solutions if they have the same problem. I've edited out your second question, but feel free to ask it separately.

Answer (score 2):

According to [this Microsoft page](http://products.office.com/en-us/home-and-student) you can only install/use Office Home & Student on one computer.